How can I update the Telegram BOT API version?
[Telegram.WebApp] Changing swipes behavior is not supported in version 6.0
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>

I'm currently using the Telegram functions and noticed that when I visit the link above, the web app version is set to 6.0. Is there a way to update it to the latest version so that I can access the new functions?
Thank you!

Initial params for this script are set from:

location params (but you have to specify the params in your url).

Like http://example.com?tgWebAppVersion=7.0


Session Storage. So you can setup session storage before tg script loading:



<script>
  function sessionStorageSet(key, value) {
    try {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('__telegram__' + key, JSON.stringify(value));
      return true;
    } catch (e) {}
    return false;
  }

  function sessionStorageGet(key) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('__telegram__' + key));
    } catch (e) {}
    return null;
  }

  var appTgVersion = 7.0;

  var initParams = sessionStorageGet('initParams');
  if (initParams) {
    if (!initParams.tgWebAppVersion) {
      initParams.tgWebAppVersion = appTgVersion;
    }
  } else {
    initParams = {
      tgWebAppVersion: appTgVersion
    };
  }

  sessionStorageSet('initParams', initParams);
</script>

<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>




Based on my observation, the version number of telegram-web-app.js is still 7.6. You can use the magic code below to disable vertical scrolling before it gets updated by Telegram.

